# Run `systemctl --user daemon-reload` for all users

Tags: systemd, scripting

Sometimes as an system administrator, after updating a shared unit file in `/etc/systemd/user/`, I would like to run `systemctl --user daemon-reload` ***for all users***. Fortunately [Systemd 248](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/28795f2c138203fb700fc394f0937708af886116/NEWS#LL2820C10-L2820C10) introduced a convenient option `-M` which allows me to connect to the user daemon of a specific user:

```bash
sudo systemctl -M other-user@ --user daemon-reload
```

... but I need to do this for every user. So right now I do this via a script:

```bash
for U in root $(ls /home); do
  sudo systemctl -M "$U@" --user daemon-reload
done
```

However this fails to account for users who either do not have a home directory, or users who have a home directory elsewhere. I can of course handle these cases by reading and parsing `/etc/passwd`, but I feel like that would be overcomplicating the issue or maybe even reinventing the wheel.

So my question is, is there an easier and more reliable way (ideally, systemd-built-in way) to do this?

Comment: There's no `systemd` way to do this. The `--global` flag does what you want but only to `enable` or `disable`. Someone requested four years ago that they make it work with other commands (like `daemon-reload`) but it was [declined](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/12770)

Comment: Note, there is *yet-another-systemd-command* `userdbctl user` which can list info from the passwd file.